# Send byte array from PHP to Java Socket

Tags: java, php, sockets

I have a java server listening on a Socket. I can send and receive data between this java server socket and java client sockets attached to it.

Now I want to connect PHP to the java server (via the java socket) but cannot seem to send a byte array (using [pack()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php)) to java.

```
$socket = fsockopen("127.0.0.1", 5477) or die("Error creating socket");

$output = pack("i3", 2, 1, 1); 
fwrite($socket, $output, 3);
```

On the java end I get a java.io.EOFException when I try to call `in.readInt()` (where `in` is a `DataInputStream`)

```
if (in.available() != 0)
{
    //read the data
    int len = in.readInt(); //length of the buffer
}
```

So what is the problem? / Am I going about this in the correct way or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing just 3 bytes to the socket, but `readInt()` **ALWAYS** reads 4 bytes to construct java `int` value.

So, you, naturally, get `EOFException` after a 3rd byte.

Comment: Oh I see. So I should change it to: `fwrite($socket, $output, 12)`? And do I need to reverse the bit order in java? (as I now when I read the length I get 33554432)

Comment: @Andrew. Java DataInputStream uses big endian byte order, so if you want to use it you must package the data accordingly on PHP side.